# cannot blit anything to screen. why not?

Tags: python, pygame

so im trying to blit tonk but its not working. can you help? all it shows is black

```
import pygame,pynput
pygame.init()

width = 700
height = 700
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))
pygame.display.set_caption('generic shooter pew pew')
Tonk = pygame.image.load("TONK.png")
screen.blit(Tonk,(0,0))

run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
            exit()

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Comment: In general, if you are using a new library and having trouble getting even the most basic thing to work, you should start by trying to copy one of the examples from the documentation. Assuming there isn't a problem with your setup, then you can start looking for differences between how that works and what you are trying to do for your own code.

Comment: its not new, i think i just forgot something and i cant figure out what

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to blit in the `while` loop and add a display update too :

```py
import pygame,pynput
pygame.init()

width = 700
height = 700
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))
pygame.display.set_caption('generic shooter pew pew')
Tonk = pygame.image.load("TONK.png")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
            exit()
    screen.blit(Tonk,(0,0))
    pygame.display.flip()

    clock.tick(60)
```

Comment: thanks! can i ask what display flip does, and why it works?

Comment: Sure! Here is the wiki link: https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip

Comment: Basically it takes everything that was added to a frame since the last one and uses it to generate a new one

Comment: i wish i could upvote this but i dont have enough rep :((